# Documentation for Stack Exchange Data Explorer Schema?

Tags: support, data-explorer, schema

Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but is there documentation on the SEDE schema anywhere? As listed here http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new, it's not obvious what all the fields are. I've had a root around, but can't find anything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most up-to-date schema reference can be found here:

[Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/what-is-the-structure-of-the-public-data-dump)

I've got that question favourited on Meta and I use it constantly.

<sub>Note: the content in that question is sourced from the documentation included with the data dump download.</sub>